What is the book series about a space witch trained by AI?
The girl gets in to a training course to become part of a planet wide exercise to train children. Learns magic from the central AI who builds up companies and teams to heal the world and go into space.

Welcome to F&SF. When did you read it? In which country? Can you remember any other details such as what the cover looked like? Hope we can help you find it.

Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy SE! To increase your chances of getting a good answer, please [edit] your question and add more details, such as when you read the book series and what works you have already checked and ruled out. For more tips on how to improve your question, take a look at our guide on asking identification questions.
